# Node.js + Express.js (Connect) - Accessing Session from 'upgrade' event

Tags: session, node.js, websocket, connect, express

I'm trying to access the session object from an 'upgrade' event fired by a Node.js server using the Express.js framework. I have set up Session support correctly and can access it from the standard .get .post .put and .delete methods eg.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.session.test = 'Hello world'; // Works fine
    res.render('index');
});
```

But if I hook up an on 'upgrade' event on the server like so:

```
app.on('upgrade', function(req, socket) {
    var message = req.session.test; // Doesn't work
});
```

I can't access the session object. As far as I'm aware, the Connect Session middleware only hooks up the session for the get/post/put/delete methods, but not for custom events such as 'upgrade'.

FYI, an 'upgrade' event is issued from a client during a WebSocket handshake, I'm trying to access the session from the initial WebSocket handshake. The session cookie is definitely there in the HTTP headers during the handshake eg:

```
app.on('upgrade', function(req, socket) {
    var cookieHeader = req.headers['cookie'];
    console.log(cookieHeader);
});
```

...will output the Connect session cookie. Is there perhaps a way to build up the session object manually using the raw session cookie token?

---

**Update:** Been speaking to to some people on the node.js IRC chatroom, apparently this is either very difficalt or impossible. The Connect middleware isn't exposed to custom/unusual events such as 'upgrade'. They said to raise an issue in Github, so here it is:

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/342

Comment: what is the "upgrade" event? what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have access to the response object, you should be able to look up the session object by getting the session store and calling `get(session_id, callback)` with the session_id you get from the cookie.  You also may be able to actually call the normal session middleware function if the `req` object you have is linked to the response via `req.res`, which express.js will do for you, but if this is a raw node.js event, then that connection might not have been made at this point.  When you create the middleware, you'll have to create the session Store instance manually and keep a reference to it, then pass it to the session middleware factory function in the `options` object.

Comment: I might try creating the session using the session store as you suggest. But the event is hooked up at node.js level.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using express-session, this should help :

```
import session from 'express-session'
import express from 'express'

import http from 'http'
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws'

// Declare an Express app 
const app = express()

// Declare an HTTP server for the app
const server = http.createServer(app)

// Initialize *express-session* and use it as a middleware
const sessionHandler = session({
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: 'my little secret',
  resave: false
})
app.use(sessionHandler)

// Define a builder for message handler with WebSocket and Session as context 
const onMessage = (ws, session) => (message) => {
    // create a handler for message given the ws and session
}

// Create a *WebSocketServer* without an attached HTTP server
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true })

// define what to do on a 'connection' event
wsServer.on('connection', (ws, session) => {
  ws.on('message', onMessage(ws, session))
})

// 'upgrade' event comes when the browser ask for a WebSocket
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
  // we call the *sessionHandler* to retrieve/create the session 
  sessionHandler(req, {}, () => {
    // ask the *WebSocketServer* to manage the upgrade
    wsServer.handleUpgrade(req, socket, head, (ws) => {
      console.log(req.session)
      // emit a 'connection' event (handler above) with the create WebSocket and current session
      wsServer.emit('connection', ws, req.session)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: what is sessionAwareProxy..

Comment: sorry sessionAwareProxy was a class in my code base to manage session. I changed it to a closure for this example

Comment: Ah okay no worries, I was hoping it contained the secret sauce to the issue I'm having where the session object only contains the cookie and not anything else.

Comment: ok sorry, I made the code more explicit and added comments. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much for this; had been trying to figure out how to validate and parse session cookies when handling a websocket upgrade.